# Terraform error on variable reference within Lambda resource that won't even be created

Tags: terraform

I have a module in Terraform 0.11.14 that creates a Lambda, with a `count` that evaluates to zero:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my-resource-name" {
   count = "${expr ? 1 : 0}"
   ...
   dead_letter_config   = {
      target_arn = "${vars.map["key"]}"  # map defaults to empty {} 
   } 
}
```

and I reference this like

```
module "my-module" {
   var1 = value
   var2 = value
}
```

The problem I'm running into is, Terraform complains about `vars.map` even though the count expression evaluates to zero.  If I supply a dummy map to satisfy Terraform, I can see that the resource is not actually being created.

The error is `map "var.map" does not have any elements so cannot determine type`.

Why is TF trying to evaluate the var within in a resource it isn't going to create?

Comment: What version of Terraform are you running?

Comment: 0.11.14 - edited question

Comment: This should work fine in 0.12 thanks to lazily evaluated conditional operators: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements/